# Java Query запрос

Tags: java, hibernate

Добрый день.

Есть Entity:

```
@Entity(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails,Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Expose
private String username;
@Expose
private String password;
@Expose
private String name;
@Expose
private String surname;
@Expose
private String phone;
@Expose
private String mail;
@Expose
@JoinColumn(name = "photo")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Photo photo;
@Expose
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user",referencedColumnName = "username")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role",referencedColumnName = "name")})
private List<UserRole>authorities = new ArrayList<>();
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "recipients")
private List<InputPost> inputPost = new ArrayList<>();
@Transient
private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
@Transient
private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
@Transient
private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
@Transient
private boolean enabled = true;

public User() {}

public User(String username) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
}

public User(String username, String password) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String phone) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String phone, String mail) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mail = mail;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String phone, String mail, Photo photo) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.photo = photo;
}

public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String phone, String mail, Photo photo,
        List<UserRole> authorities) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setPhoto(Photo photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public Photo getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

@Override
public List<UserRole> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(List<UserRole> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public List<InputPost> getInputPost() {
    return inputPost;
}

public void setInputPost(List<InputPost> inputPost) {
    this.inputPost = inputPost;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return accountNonExpired;
}

public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
    this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return accountNonLocked;
}

public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
    this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return credentialsNonExpired;
}

public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
    this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname
            + ", phone=" + phone + ", mail=" + mail + ", photo=" + photo + ", authorities=" + authorities
            + ", inputPost=" + inputPost + "]";
}
}
```

и данный запрос:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
private String mySql;

public User get(String mail) {
    Query query = null;
    mySql = "FROM User u WHERE u.mail=:mail";
    query = em.createQuery(mySql,User.class);
    query.setParameter("mail",mail);

    return (User)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

выдает:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not
>   mapped [FROM Users u WHERE u.mail=:mail]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not
>   mapped [FROM Users u WHERE u.mail=:mail]

**Вопрос:** почему?

Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47701/discussion-on-question-by---java-query-).

Answer (score 1):

Фух...Разобрался....

```
mySql = "FROM User u WHERE u.mail=:mail";
```

При этом убрал `Entity(name="users")` и оставил просто `Entity`.